# Getting string between characters in Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a list of strings with the  output below

```
      stop = F6, quantity ( 1 )                        // stop 0
      stop = F8, quantity ( 1 )                        // stop 1
      stop = BN, quantity ( 1 )                        // stop 2
      stop = F6, quantity ( 1 )                        // stop 3
      stop = F8, quantity ( 1 )                        // stop 4
      stop = BN, quantity ( 1 )                        // stop 5
      stop = F6, quantity ( 1 )                        // stop 6
      stop = F8, quantity ( 1 )                        // stop 7
      stop = SC, quantity ( 1 )                        // stop 8
etc
```

using a foreach loop i'm retrieving each line in the list ie

```
`stop = F6, quantity ( 1 )                        // stop 0`
```

However I only need the character F6.
I Know I need to use regex to retrieve f6 in this instance, however, I am unsure on the expression. From a brief tutorial on regex, I've tried using the code below to achieve this with no luck

```
`Regex.Match(output, @"=\w*,").Value.Replace("\"", "");`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the symbol after the f6" in your example? What is your expected output for this line?

Comment: "the symbol after the f6" - so... you only need the `,`? If not, could you state exactly what you need from that samplle string?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. Modified the question

Comment: Expected output is F6, F8,BN, etc

Comment: `\bstop = (?<code>\w{2})\b` ::  match["code"] -> 'F6'

Comment: `Regex.Match(inputString, @"^\s+stop = (.{2})").Groups[1].Value`

Comment: Regex buddy is really good for this sort of thing - no, I'm not the author ;-) - https://www.regexbuddy.com/ There are also online tools, just search "for c# regex tester" or some similar phrase.

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, works a treat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
"=\\s([A-Za-z0-9]{2}),"
//or
"=\\s(\\w+),"
```

Code:

```
string str = "stop = F6, quantity ( 1 )  ";
var res = Regex.Matches(str, "=\\s([A-Za-z0-9]{2}),")[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much in C# but you're regex is this : `"= (\w+),"`. That regex get any words/digit between `=` and `,`.

In regex, an expression between parenthesis is call a "Capturing Group". In any languages you have some API to retrieve content capture in capturing group. I found this for C# : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx

So the code for retrieve you're data look like that :

```
String pattern = @"=\\s(\\w+),";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Value : {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

To test you're regex in live, https://regex101.com/ is so usefull ! Use it to see visually what the regex request do while you write it.

Comment: The regex surround effectively `=` and `,` but the `(` and `)` permit to capture the content inside, so in this case the "F6" content. The content is retrieve by using `match.Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted something in your answer yesterday. If you edit something, I can retract my downvote.